# RactJs/Laravel -problem with not being able to submit a form

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel

I have this form and I am not able to 'submit', the following error message appears, when I click on the 'submit ' button

**ReactJS File:**

```
...//rest of the code omitted

function onSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_URL}/api/orders/csv`
      , values
    ).then((response) => {
      history.push('/orders/csv')
      console.log('response: ')
      console.log(response)
    })
  }


...//rest of the code omitted
      <Modal.Body className="py-0 border">
            {!isModalLoading ? (
              <Fragment>
                <form method="post" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                  <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                    <label className="col-md-3 label-control form-label">Tenants</label>
                    <div className="col-md-8">

                      <Select
                        options={contractsOptions}
                        onChange={obj => dispatch(selectContract(obj && obj.value ? obj.value : ''))}
                        name="tenants"
                        id="tenants"
                        className="select-group"
                        isSearchable={true}
                        placeholder={<div>Tenants</div>}
                        isClearable={true}
                        theme={headerSelectTheme}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                    <label htmlFor="date" className="col-md-3 label-control form-label">
                      First Date</label>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                      <input
                        name="first_date"
                        id="date"
                        type="date"
                        className="form-control"
                        onChange={onChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                    <label htmlFor="date" className="col-md-3 label-control form-label">
                      End Date</label>
                    <div className="col-md-8">
                      <input
                        name="end_date"
                        id="date"
                        type="date"
                        className="form-control"
                        onChange={onChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </Fragment>
            ) : (
              <SpinnerLoading />
            )}
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            {!isModalLoading ? (
              <>
                <div>
                  <Button onClick={() => setModal(false)}>Cancel</Button>
                </div>
                <div>
                
                  <Button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="px-3">Export CSV</Button>
                </div>
              </>
            ) : (<></>)}
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
 ...//rest of the code omitted
```

**Laravel(Version 5.8) Route File:**

```
  ...//rest of the code omitted
$api->get('orders/csv', function () {
    return 'Orders CSV';
});
  ...//rest of the code omitted
```

**Error Message**

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
> (Method Not Allowed) createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error:
> Request failed with status code 405 at createError (createError.js:17)
> at settle (settle.js:19) at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:63)

how do i fix it? Thanks.

Comment: mentions route  of laravel doesnt match reactjs axios post.  get('orders/csv' but in axios its api/orders/orders-csv and laravel has get request and axios post request.look like you have posted wrong route

Comment: Thank you, but how to fix it?

Comment: first add post request route and test from postman so that you can make sure server side works fine .or else you might difficult to identify what causing an issue

Comment: @JohnLobo Now I tested it from postman, and there appeared an error message:
  "message": "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, DELETE.",
    "status_code": 405,

Comment: please post all routes in question and postman screenshot